# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘CGPfunctions’

Tags: r, package

I'm trying to load

```
library(CGPfunctions)
```

but I obtain

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘CGPfunctions’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘lme4’

Do you know the reason?

I'm using OS 12.2
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)

Comment: Try `install.packages("lme4")`, the error message is self explanatory.

Comment: The reason is that you don't have the lme4 package installed. Run `install.packages("lme4")`

Comment: Done, Thanks!!!